# Project Solution | Architecture | Scenes and Views

Tags: unity-game-engine, architecture

Im new in Game Dev and new in development with Unity 
(Come from Windows and Web development)

Now I want to make my first game. This will simple game (but with retrieve data from API etc.)

So I have some basic questions:

1)   How to decide if I need to make new scene or build just make a lot canvases and switch between them?

In my game I see

```
1 scene - Loading
2 scene - Main screen with buttons--
1 button - open Store
2 button Open leaderborad
3 button - open something like map
```

etc...

Now I think

I need make 2 scenes - Loading and Game scene

In Game scene make some canvases
(MainState Canvas, Shop Canvas, MapCanvas, Leader board canvas etc...)

And when user clicks on button - show this canvas (its must be display like Popup)

2) If I want that map will grow up with more and more stop points (like in Candy Crush) - I need to set its to Assets Bundle and load new bundle ?

3) Best practices for Login/Authorization 
I check many sites and I see that best practices for Game Authorization today - this is Google/Apple Game service and not Facebook. Right?

If I understand not correct - Can you guys give me a links what I need to read/learn ?

Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are targeting mobiles.

1) On mobiles the decision is simple in this case. One simple scene, that is loading fast, to show your logo, game title etc. and the second scene to all other stuff. If the game has very complex levels you can start thinking about more scenes. (If it's simple and easy to change to next level, e.g change background, some enemies etc. like in your case I would use one scene)

2) Sorry I don't know what you want to achieve, but you can read about Asset Bundles [here](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/04/12/asset-bundles-vs-resources-a-memory-showdown/) and in unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html). Again it depends on the complexity of the project. For a simple game it may not be a big difference. Official unity [video on Asset Bundles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGULjJV7Kh0) and about [Bundle browser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1kslvqXAq8)

3) I have no idea about Apple Game service so I will talk only about Google Services. It's really simple to setup. However some steps may be tricky, but take your time and try to setup everything as you need. The [github page of google play games plugin for unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity), where you can download the latest build of the plugin, contains a lot of information on how to configure it. Docs I mentioned above and some testing was enough to implement it in my games. However if you have troubles with setting it up there are a few videos on youtube when you can see how to configure it step by step. Also here is the [site](https://resocoder.com/2017/03/10/gpg-tutorial-saved-games-code/) on which you can see how your code should look after implementing google play games